# Does passing through a colored medium cause light to become that color or to lose that color? Why is the atmosphere different?

Tags: optics, visible-light

It's well known the effect of Rayleigh scattering on the color of the sun, and it's explained several times on this website. Here's [one of them](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/99753/248454). The summary of these explanations is, that when light travels through a colored medium, that color is being "used up" to make the medium the color it is, and only the other colors will go through.

Make very much sense. But the problem is that our experience in everyday life is **just the opposite**. When we shine a light through a colored medium, the light becomes **the same color** as the medium. Although it's hard for me to understand why (this was asked [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/279712/248454) without an impressive answer). And that's also happening with sunlight that goes through colored glass.

So why does the atmosphere behave different than anything else? And is there anything I can experiment with that would have the same behavior as the atmosphere?

Comment: Your title would be more satisfactory to nit-pickers if it said "does passing _white_ light through..."  Unless there's some nonlinear phenomenon going on (florescence or frequency doubling) passing monochrome light through a medium won't _change_ its color -- it'll just alter the amplitude and possibly direction of the light.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two mechanisms that lead to extinction of light:

- Scattering,
- Absorption.

Most everyday materials like e.g. colored glasses or transparent colored plastics absorb light, which means that they take some frequencies away, and reflect+transmit the remaining ones, which means that the color you see them have is also the color they turn light into when looked through.

But in the atmosphere, namely the troposphere, the dominant extinction mechanism is scattering, which indeed leads to the scattered light being blue while the transmitted part is orange. In the stratosphere, in addition to Rayleigh scattering by (mostly) nitrogen and oxygen molecules, there's an ozone layer, which makes the light [bluer by absorption](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chappuis_absorption). This makes the twilight blue instead of sandy-colored that it would have without ozone.

Aside from atmosphere, you can see such scattering extinction in some other materials via the [Tyndall effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tyndall_effect). E.g. opalescent glass can exhibit this (image from the article linked):

[image]

Another example of such behavior is in coated glass, where the coating uses interference of light to enhance transmission of some frequencies or to reflect them efficiently. In particular, you might have noticed that typical medical eyeglasses reflect purplish light when turned into one orientation, and greenish when in another.

Comment: I would rather say that there's one mechanism to extinction of light: Absorption. Scattering is very similar to reflection of ordinary materials, which also reflects in all directions. So I guess the amount of light lost to that must be similar (and that bothered me in the question). The key is that with ordinary materials there is absorption and with scattering materials there's not.
So in both cases the color which is reflected/scattered is also transmitted to a similar extent, but with scattering it's overwhelmed by the color which wasn't scattered.
That sounds right?

Comment: @GeorgeLee Extinction of light is loss of radiance per unit path length. Scattering also contributes to it, so it's not correct to say that it's not a mechanism of extinction. Both absorption and scattering can be described by effective cross sections, and generally these both concepts are very important in radiative transfer computations. The result that you see depends not on _presence_ of absorption, but rather on the balance between scattering and absorption, both of which always exist, but one or both can become negligible.

Comment: In that sense maybe reflection to directions other then forward is also a mechanism of extinction.

Comment: My point was that the (almost) lack of absorption plays a bigger role (or even the entire role) than the difference of scattering vs reflection. Is that right?

Comment: @GeorgeLee I'm not sure what you mean. If absorption is negligible, then naturally you only have scattering, which is what makes up the final transmitted (and out-scattered) color.

Comment: Regarding the experiment: The Wikipedia page you link, cites https://www.thoughtco.com/definition-of-tyndall-effect-605756 for that glass, but the cited article doesn't mention it. At [another page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Opalescence), they cite a different source for that same experiment, which also doesn't mention it, but does show a different experiment at a different page: https://www.webexhibits.org/causesofcolor/14F.html - an experiment with water and milk.

Comment: ...The milk experiment is found in overall in the web. But it's greatly exaggerated to say the least. I followed the instructions fairly good, and the "redness" of the light (if any) wasn't anything compared to the pictures on these articles, which I can assume are fake.

Comment: @GeorgeLee actually no, I've just tried this experiment as described in your last link, and the transmitted light does look reddish-orange. I can show you my photos if you want, even CR2 if you won't believe a JPEG ;D

Comment: @GeorgeLee two CR2 files are available [here](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1roak9Zpx5_Xj8rfDV4XGx67eeNI6_NeX?usp=sharing). In the view from above the red spot is the transmitted light from a phone LED flashlight. In the view from the side you can notice how the outscattered light gets yellower as it goes farther from the bottom (the glass stands on the phone).

Comment: Sorry, in the view from the side I see nothing special. But the first picture indeed shows reddening. (So we can still assume that these pictures on the web are fake.)

Comment: @GeorgeLee which pictures do you think to be fake? The ones in your last link (3 views from top) seem compatible with mine.

Comment: Regarding the eyeglasses phenomenon: This was taken care of here: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/415594/weird-reflection-pattern-in-reading-glasses, and I don't think it's very much related to my question.

Answer (score 0):

You're confusing 2 different things.

1. Atmospheric scattering, Rayleigh scattering.  In this process, the molecules of air act as dipoles and as such they respond to light and reradiate the light.  But when they reradiate the light it has a strong wavelength dependence that scales as the the inverse of Wavelength^4.  Since blue light is ~400 nm, and red is ~800 nm in wavelength, blue light will be much more strongly scattered. While the longer wavelengths (eg. red) will be less scattered. The scattering occurs at 90 degrees relative to the incident light.  If you look at a sunset it appears more red.  This is because the blue is scattered away at 90 degrees.
2. Absorption in a material.  Here, there are molecular states, or electric states that will absorb certain colors of light, and in some cases will couple the energy gained by the atoms or molecules to the lattice as heat.  So the light is lost. So if I have 2 colors of lights (W1, and W2) and the material absorbs W1, then only W2 will emerge.  W1 is lost to heat.

Answer (score -1):

I think you got it the wrong way round. The light that is seen through a colored glass is the specific wavelength which is **not** scattered.

The medium doesn't need to "use up" (absorb) the light to be that color, rather letting the light through and scattering every other wavelength. Maybe it is unintuitive, because one could think of color as a possession. It would then make sense for an object to absorb a certain wavelength to "posses" a color, but that's not true.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: By "use up" I don't mean "absorb", I mean scatter. The point is that **it's not going through**.

Comment: "The light that is seen **through** a colored glass is the specific wavelength which is not scattered" – And what about the color of the glass itself? Is it also the color which is not being scattered? These are both the same color! So the scattered color is invisible?

Comment: well, if the medium is transparent at color "c", then you are not seeing "c" scattered; rather you are seeing "c" that passes through it from the other side?

Comment: The color of the glass and the color which passes through are the same. You are not seeing the wavelengths scattered inside the glass, but the ones which are led through. If a glass is red, it means that only red light can pass through. The scattered color is "invisible" in the sense, that it's not focused on your eye, rather scattered at every angle. In return, the color has a very low intensity.

Comment: The color we see on the sky is the one that **is scattered**. Scatter doesn't mean absorb.